# jQuery add css class only when last child element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a css class to parent if the last child is in visible range.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="left"></div>

<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>

<li>Item 2</li>

<li>Item 3</li>

<li>Item 4</li>

More items will be here

<li id="last-child">Last item</li>

</ul>
<div class="right">

<p> Some content </p>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.left{position:absolute;}

.left-fixed{position:fixed;}
```

So when the #last-child is in visible range I want to add css class .left-fixed to div class .left

3 things I want to achieve.

1. When window load if `#last-child` is visible add css class `.left-fixed`
2. If window is resize `#last-child` visible css class `.left-fixed` and remove if not visible
3. When scroll `#last-child` visible css class `.left-fixed` and remove if not visible on scroll.

Can someone point me a way to achieve this? I search but couldn’t find an answer to these questions. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.getBoundingClientRect()`, `window.innerHeight`

```
const last = $("#last-child")[0];
const left = $(".left");

$(window).on("resize", function(event) {
  if ((last.getBoundingClientRect().top < -(last.clientHeight) 
  || last.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > window.innerHeight)) {
    if (!left.is(".left-fixed")) {
      left.addClass("left-fixed");
    }
  } else {
    if (left.is(".left-fixed")) {
      left.removeClass("left-fixed")
    }
  }
}).resize();
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hfv89veu/3/

Comment: Thanks all. All solutions work great. Im just going to use this solutions. Thank you so much guest271314

Answer (score 2):

Very simple!

**jQuery**:

```
if($("#last-child").is(":visible")){
    $(".left").addClass("left-fixed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  CheckLastVisible();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    CheckLastVisible();
  });
});

function CheckLastVisible(){
  if($("#last-child").is(":visible")){
      $("#last-child").parents(".left:eq(0)").addClass("left-fixed");
  }
  else{
     $("#last-child").parents(".left:eq(0)").removeClass("left-fixed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use jquery :

```
//When window load if #last-child is visible add css class .left-fixed

if($("#last-child").is(":visible")){
    $(this).parent().addClass("left-fixed");
}

//If window is resize #last-child visible css class .left-fixed and remove if //not visible
if($("#last-child").is(":visible")){
    $(this).parent().addClass("left-fixed");
}
else{
   $(this).parent().removeclass("left-fixed");
}
```

//  there is one more way to do this without using jquery:

```
.last-child{ display:none; }
.parent:hover .last-child{ display:block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 iflastvisible();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    iflastvisible();
  });
});

function iflastvisible(){
  if($("#last-child").is(":visible")){
      $("#last-child").parents(".left:eq(0)").addClass("left-fixed");
  }
else{
 $("#last-child").parents(".left:eq(0)").removeClass("left-fixed");
}
}
```